# Access Model Data from Django Base Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model `Category`, and I want its objects to always be displayed in a navigation menu in my `base.html` template *(which all of my other templates extend)*.

I want to learn best-practices so would like to know what the correct/accepted way of providing this data to the template is.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "I want its objects to always be displayed in a menu". Could you give an example? I can think of a number of ways to do this. This is just so that I can give you the exact answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't explicit. All I want to do is to be able to iterate through Category.objects.all() some way or another in my main ase template. I'll edit the question and have another stab at wording it with an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a [custom tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for the categories and place it in the base template. That way you wont have to send a "category" variable to the context on every view ..

Good Luck

Comment: +1 for good solution (I'd also do it this way), but you might want to detail it a bit more.

Comment: Ah, inclusion tags look like they'll help me out here. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Use a custom context processor:

In context_processors.py:

```
def categories(request):
    return {
        'categories': Categories.objects.all()
    }
```

And add it to your settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ... django's default context processors
    "your_app.context_processors.categories", 
)
```

Comment: I've just used it in a project and it's a very flexible and elegant solution! However also inclusion tags are a good solution

Comment: Careful though; the context processor will not refresh the value as long as the Django app isn't reloaded, so if you want to access anything that's likely to change, you should use a template tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up for anyone using later versions of Django (i.e. 1.9): the way that Django defines its context processors has changed. Instead of adding to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` you can just add a line to Django's list of context processors:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'app.context_processors.your_processor', # CHANGE THIS
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Hope this helps!